# How to add User to Group in a user pool in AWS Cognito using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I have a web app where I would like to be able to set the usergroups in Cognito on users from a Web UI we offer, not in AWS portal. Problem is that I don't find any implementation of this to use. Any ideas on how I can do this?

For example, if I want to assign User A to Group B in my User Pool (prod-users). How can I achieve that?

I only found JS example of doing this, and I might be able to add a Lambda Function to be able to do this but I would rater have it in my main project

Comment: In your description, it seems that A and B have a one-to-many relationship? If you want to add A to B, then you can look at how to add one-to-many relationship data in EFCore.

Comment: Maybe my question wasnät 100% clear, I meant in AWS I will update the question!